# moment.js get the last saturday

Tags: momentjs

I want to use

> .startOf('day')

on last saturday, and if today is saturday, I want to get the start of today. I tried this but is seems not working:

> moment().isoWeekday("Saturday").startOf('day')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
const today = moment();

const lastSat = today.isoWeekday(-1);
const startDayOfLastSat= lastSat.startOf('day')
```